# Koa2 Server Return binary data

Tags: node.js, koa2

I have a little Koa2 Application running in node v7.7.3

My `koa-router` handler function for `/capture` is called correctly and my webcam takes a shot. But for some reason I am not able to return the resulting Buffer in cmd.stdout ... and yes the Buffer is filled.

```
router.get(['/capture'], function (ctx, next) {
    const cmd = spawn('fswebcam', ['-r800x600', '-S1', '--jpeg', '100', '--device', '/dev/video1', '--timestamp', '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S (%Z)', '-']);
    console.log(cmd.status);
    console.log(cmd.stdout);
    this.body = cmd.stdout;
    return cmd.stdout;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If your cmd.stdout is filled correctly, you should return your data this way:

```
router.get(['/capture'], function (ctx, next) {

    ...

    console.log(cmd.stdout);
    this.body = cmd.stdout;

    // provide an appropriate  MIME type 
    ctx.type = 'image/jpeg';    // if it is an jpeg

    // return the data in the ctx.body
    ctx.body = cmd.stdout;
});
```